# If I want to create game for mobile and tablet on android and ios, which aspect ratio or screen resolution should I use?

Tags: android, game-design, aspect-ratio

Now my game is currently use 3:4 aspect ratio ,which is 480*640
, so my game has the letterbox (I don't like stretch) on my android mobile and my friend mobile. I don't like letterbox, so I have just change color of my letter box to the color that blend with my game background, but I don't like it either. So now I think about change aspect ratio and screen resolution of my game.

how about 480x800 ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all of the aspect ratios you have to handle:

- 4:3
- 3:2
- 8:5
- 5:3
- 16:9

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199492/what-are-the-aspect-ratios-for-all-android-phone-and-tablet-devices

Create 5 sets of graphics or use an engine like LibGDX and it's https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

@Edit
When creating a LibGDX app, you can set width/height parameters

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.title = "Game Title";
cfg.height = 640;
cfg.width = 360;
```

(This is in your Core project in Eclipse/Intellij/Netbeans whatever).

When you set this, you can resize your window and check if it's a good resolution and if things are scaling well.

Comment: My game also using LibGDX. I using 3:4 aspect ratio but realize that it's not fit with nowaday mobiles. I also using fit viewport , so it has letterbox, I not using stretch viewport because my game is going to ugly. Could you recommend me which aspect ratio should I use ? and what aspect ratio most nowaday mobile game is using ?. I use strategy that setup my game to use one fixed resolution (480x640) and using fitviewport to scale up or down to any mobile resolution.

Comment: You will never fit all mobile devices with one aspect ratio. You can try with 4:3 it will work probably the best and you should test it on multiple resolutions. In LibGDX when you create your game with ApplicationAdapter you can set it's parameters with width and height (I have edited my answer). Then, you can resize your window and test if your viewports scales things perfectly. Without 5 sets of graphics you won't be able to fit all of the screens, you will always have black space in left/right sides.

Comment: I think using "5 sets of graphics" can be difficult task to handle for me now (do you have some tutorial for this ?). I've tested that using 4:3 on other aspect ratio has so much letterbox than 5:3, So now I think I'm going to change my game from 4:3 to 5:3 instead of using "5 sets of graphics". Do you agree with me ?

Comment: If you can't make 5 sets of graphics - of course, your solution will be okay :) A agree!

Comment: My suggestion is just cosmetic.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to mark one of the answers correct when you think it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide alternative resources for different screen ratios.